# Editing Duplicated Symbol individually flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, symbols, flash-cc

i am trying to edit an instance of my symbol.

Every time i do this it changes both the original and the duplicated symbols.

Any idea's why this is happening?

Original Symbol Before Edit : `http://imgur.com/N7EyGlx`

Duplicated Symbol after Edit : `http://imgur.com/OtyWGw7`

Original Symbol after Edit : `http://imgur.com/N7EyGlx`

Answer (score 0):

There's exactly the same symbol in the 3 examples you sent. You can’t change an instance of your class. If you double-click on your instance for editing, this is the class that you are going to change, then you will change all instances of this class that you have put on your scene.